# Can I use tsc --watch for type checking only with esbuild

Tags: typescript, esbuild

when run `tsc --noEmit --incremental` it takes 17s to finish. To increase speed, tsc offers watch mode. Now it only takes ~2 seconds

This is my script

```
// type checking
tsc --noEmit --incremental

// build
node ./build-with-esbuild.js
```

the build script has his own watcher. How I can use `tsc --watch` and build script?

Answer (score 0):

My solution by using stdio pipe and detecting tsc has finished. I end up removing the watcher from build as I rely on tsc watcher now

```
import { execSync, spawn } from 'child_process';

const tschecking = spawn(
    `npx tsc --watch --incremental --tsBuildInfoFile ${DIR}/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo`,
    [],
    {
        cwd: SERVICE_DIR,
        stdio: 'pipe',
        shell: true,
    }
);

/**
 * Run build after ts checking done
 */
tschecking.stdout.on('data', (data: any): any => {
    const output = data.toString();
    console.log(output);
    // when tsc outputs below string that means it has done type checking.
    if (output.includes('Watching for file changes')) {
        build();
    }
});
```